# How can I fix my shadow caster problem?

Tags: unity, fragment-shader, shadows, shaderlab

I'm trying to make invisible object with shadow by using it's shadow castting pass it additionaly shades back side of object itself. I mean object shades his back side and draws shadow on the background surface.(my unity version is Unity 5.6)

you can see this problem in below animated gif:

[image: shadow caster problem]

this is my shader for unity's shadow pass:

```
Shader "Test/ShadowCaster"
{
    SubShader
    {
    Tags{ "LightMode" = "ShadowCaster"  }
    Name "ShadowCaster"
        Pass
    {
        CGPROGRAM

#pragma vertex vert
#pragma fragment frag
#pragma multi_compile_shadowcaster
#pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest

#include "UnityCG.cginc"

        struct v2f
    {
        V2F_SHADOW_CASTER;
    };

    v2f vert(appdata_base v)
    {
        v2f o;
        TRANSFER_SHADOW_CASTER_NORMALOFFSET(o)
        return o;
    }

    float4 frag(v2f i) : COLOR
    {
        SHADOW_CASTER_FRAGMENT(i)
    }
        ENDCG
    }
    }
        FallBack Off
}
```

Comment: You can do this without a special shader by setting the object's renderer mode to Shadows Only.

Comment: @DMGregory that's right but I [had problem](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/153534/how-can-i-animating-shadow-in-surface-shader) In my shader that it only fixed by using shadow caster in shader.in vertex and fragment shader you can't do it so I have to write it from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adding `Transparent` Queue tag to my shader.

```
Tags{ "Queue" = "Transparent" "LightMode" = "ShadowCaster" }
```

[image: 2018-01-24_8-08-47]

> Transparent - this render queue is rendered after Geometry and AlphaTest, in back-to-front order. Anything alpha-blended (i.e. shaders that don’t write to depth buffer) should go here (glass, particle effects).
>
> https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-SubShaderTags.html

[Useful link](http://www.shadercat.com/how-to-explore-unity-5s-shader-system-code-v-shadows-code-overview/) for learning shadow casters in unity.