# How can I animate shadow in surface shader?

Tags: unity, shadows, surface-shader

I wrote wind shader that works but as you can see it have shadow problem!
when I animating vertices shadow is fixed!

[image]

```
Shader "Smkgames/Wind Shader" {
        Properties{
            _MainTex("Albedo and alpha (RGBA)", 2D) = "white" {}
            _BumpTex("BumpTex",2D) = "bump"{}
            _WindMap ("WindMap", 2D) = "white" {} // Add noies map like fbm noises
            _Cutoff ("Cutoff", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
            _Speed("Speed",float) = 1
            _Direction("Direction",Vector) = (0,0.2,0,0)
        }

        SubShader{
            Cull Off

            Tags{ "Queue" = "Transparent" "IgnoreProjector" = "True" "RenderType" = "TransparentCutout" "DisableBatching"="True" }
            LOD 200

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma surface surf Standard alphatest:_Cutoff vertex:vert

            #pragma target 3.0

            sampler2D _MainTex,_WindMap,_BumpTex;
            fixed4 _Direction;
            fixed _Speed, _WindAmount;
            half _Glossiness, _Metallic;
            fixed4 _Color;

            void vert(inout appdata_full v) {
            float4 tex = tex2Dlod(_WindMap, float4(v.texcoord.xy + (_Time.x * _Speed), 0, 0));
            v.vertex.xyz += tex.y *  _Direction.xyz * _Speed;
            }

            struct Input {
                float2 uv_MainTex;
                float2 uv_BumpTex;
            };

            void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {
                fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex);
                o.Albedo = c.rgb;
                o.Alpha = c.a;
                o.Normal = UnpackNormal(tex2D(_BumpTex,IN.uv_BumpTex));
            }
            ENDCG
        }
                FallBack "VertexLit"
    }
```

I couldn't fix it! so I tried to add shadow to my object from scratch by using vertex and fragment shader shadow caster and worked correctly but I want know
Is there a way to fixing this problem in surface shader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add "addshadow" to your `#pragma surface surf Standard alphatest:_Cutoff vertex:vert` line. Boom Unity does the rest. So it looks like this :

```
#pragma surface surf Standard alphatest:_Cutoff vertex:vert addshadow
```